# Cannot able to deploy the solution from VS2015 in SharePoint 2016

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, solution-deployment, 2016, visual-studio-2015

Recently, I am getting this below error, while deploying the solution from Visual Studio 2015 or using PowerShell commands in the SharePoint 2016 server.

**Error:**

> Error occurred in deployment step 'Retract Solution': The
>   language-neutral solution package was not found.

I have tried several solutions defined in below links but none of them works for me.

- https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kunal_mukherjee/2012/11/12/error-cannot-uninstall-language-pack-0-because-it-is-not-deployed-when-attempting-to-uninstall-spsolution-on-sharepoint-2010-foundation/
- http://ehikioya.com/the-language-neutral-solution-package-was-not-found/
- https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/6689e84f-a6a4-4ca8-bddf-87c23eb8bdbf/error-occurred-in-deployment-step-retract-solution-the-languageneutral-solution-package-was-not?forum=sharepointgeneralprevious
- http://sharepointhelper2010.blogspot.in/2012/11/error-occurred-in-deployment-step.html

Any help would be appreciated!